# Regex for a string of capitalized words?

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that will pull out the phrases of capitalized `[a-z]` words. So if it  sees this phrase it should pull out "America Fremerica" and "King" from

```
there is a land called America Fremerica where regex is King
```

I have a regex `([A-Z][a-z]+ ?){1,}` that pulls out Fremerica and King.

I want it to pick out `America Fremerica`. Why doesn't it pick out `America`? Is that why it does not pick out the phrase?

Comment: Instead of search for an optional space, why not a word boundary like \b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex works, but it's not **capturing** all of the words. The regex `(a)+` will match the string `aaa` but it will only capture the last `a`. To capture all three `a`s you'd need to write `(a+)` with the wildcard inside the parentheses.

So put another set of parentheses around the whole thing. You want to capture the repetitions. You can also change `{1,}` to `+`, which is equivalent.

```
((?:[A-Z][a-z]+ ?)+)
```

`?:` stops the inner set of parentheses from being a capture group. It's not necessary, but it's nice to have.

Comment: can you explain why that works? I thought parens group items.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex captures the trailing space. This regex captures a capitalized word followed by 0-n more such words (either as the whole match or group 1 - they are the same), which captures just `"America Fremerica"` (not `"America Fremerica "`)

```
([A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*)
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/zamNcZrzaL)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work as expected in Javascript.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9X83F/2/

HTML

```
<p id="result"></p>
```

Javascript

```
var phrase = "there is a land called America Fremerica where regex is King";
var matches = phrase.match(/([A-Z][a-z]+ ?){1,}/g);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = matches;
```